# Add script tag to React component without using props or context in NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I want to add a library to my React component as a script tag. I'm doing this currently by calling an API in an _app.tsx file then accessing the value in a _document.tsx file. Within _document.tsx I add the script tag to the document head by passing it to a custom component.

My ultimate goal is to remove it from NEXT_DATA (I'm working on a SSR Next JS app).

Any ideas? I've looked into using window, but have not had success there.

Note: Updated question for clairty.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Next.js `Head` tag from anywhere in your app to achieve loading a script.

For example:

```js
    import Head from 'next/head';
    
    function MyLibraryLoader() {
        return (
            <Head>
                <script src="..." type="text/javascript" />
            </Head>
        )
    }
```

More about the Head tag can be found here:
https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/head

Comment: I don’t think this addresses my problem. I have access to the script within getInitialProps and where I do Axios calls to retrieve the values. But I need to get the script to my Head and Body components. I want to get it to the Head and Body components without using props or context.

Unless I misunderstand, what you are pointing me to is the same thing I’m already doing for Head and Body. I would need to pass the script into the function.

Comment: To add more context, I call an API in App.getInitialProps inside a custom _app file. I then add a value from the call to a custom Head (document/head) component that's initialized in a custom _document file.

Comment: Can you give a code example? Im not sure I understand what you are trying to do. Which values are coming from the server?